# Android table view

Tags: java, android

I need to create a table layout similar to this http://sourceforge.net/dbimage.php?id=194965
I need some example source code on how to do this.

Comment: Hey not sure what type of layout it is. But still i got something which may help you. http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure it is a TableLayout?? For me it looks like a ListView. If i'm wrong I'm curious how they remove elements from Table? I've looked to Documentation and don't find any method for removing elements. Maybe they generate then a new Table from beginning and replace old one?
I really thing its a better way to use here a ListView, what do you thing ppl?

Answer (score 1):

There are many excellent examples for TableLayout and other views and layouts on the Android developers site:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basics of setting up an android gridview:
http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Obviously you'll need a little work to get to the desired result, but it's a good start from the standard android lib. This example places pictures in the grid, you'll want text or other stuff. That means tweaking the example. The gridview is not meant specifically for pictures, but in the example that's what its is used for. You'll have to bend that to text.