# Implementing Table View in Android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542655/android-table-view)

I have pretty much the same question as was [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542655/android-table-view) a year ago - how to implement table view widget in a nice manner, like on [this screenshot](http://sourceforge.net/dbimage.php?id=194965). There wasn't a good answer to that question, so reposting.

I used `ListView` with a `LinearLayout` as its row, which contains several `TextView` elements and an `ImageView`. But the trouble is that each row is completely independent from the others in terms of column width. If a column in one row has text that's longer than in another, the two won't be aligned vertically. And `GridView` doesn't seem to be appropriate for my case, because it is meant to display homogenious data that is stored in a list and just display it in the columns - like grid of pictures. Any idea how this could be implemented? Thanks.

**Update.**
OK, I've just found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4987097/714011). In my Linear layout for a table row, despite setting `android:layout_weight` I was mistakenly setting `android:layout_width` to `wrap_content`. Setting it to `0dip` made all TextView's in the LinearLayout have the same width in every row. Here's the example of my row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="6dip">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toptext"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:textSize="24sp"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:textSize="24sp" 
/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/play_1"
    android:clickable="true"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: does jquery mobile help? just a thought

Comment: You should read up on layouts. RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, GridLayout etc. They are combined to make the layout you see there. I can give you some clues (I haven't coded android for months...): You can obviously see that they used a GridLayout with 5 columns in that case (or Layouts where they have assigned weight to each column) Then probably just substring the text to max 4 characthers or whatever you like and fit. It is many ways of achieving this

Comment: As it was pointed out by GrAnd Layouts aren't meant to display large amounts of data, that is my case unfortunately. @visista I initially tried Sencha Touch with phonegap for this project, but the amount of RAM the prototype used was unacceptable(22Mb), so I decided to go native.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate desired widths of cells the table must know all its rows and cells widths based on data. The `ListView` does not know all info at once, so it can't do such calculations. The are two solutions, IMHO.

1. Define fixed widths for `ListView` row items. This approach will consume as low resources as can and capable support about unlimited lists.
2. Make `TableLayout` to behave like `ListView` (at least visually). [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873556/focusable-row-inside-table-android/5258310#5258310) my answer how to implement it. But this solution is fine only if the table does not have a lot of rows (<100 is ok, I think), because it will load all date at once, even the invisible in a particular time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I very much prefer the first option, as I need it to scale to a big amount of data. Fixed widths approach is a bit worrying to me, because I will tie my app to a particular screen resolution, and there are a lot of android phones with different resolutions. But I guess I can implement some code to calculate width of each column at runtime by iterating over the data..

Comment: You don't need to do fixed pixel widths, you can do "fixed" percentage widths by using a `LinearLayout` and setting weights to simulate columns.

Comment: I was actually setting weghts for items in LinearLayout, but the items were still misaligned.